# How to show array result in ajax success using codeigniter?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am fetching values from data using where in() mysql query and I got the correct result, but I don't know how to display the result in ajax success.

How do I display company name and email id from result data set?

my ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('#ok').on('click', function() { 
  
  var vals  = $('#show').val();
  
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>email/get_company",
                data: { vals:vals },
                datatype: 'json',
               success: function (data) { 
                alert(data);
                $("#result").html(data);
               
                var result = JSON.parse(data);

}
 });


});
</script>
```

my controller code:

```
function get_company()
{

$vals = $this->input->post('vals');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM customer` where company_id IN ($vals) ")->result();

 echo json_encode($query);
}
```

my result:

```
[{"company_name":"xyz Ltd","company_email":"123@gmail.com"},{"company_name":"wer Jit","company_email":"2222@gmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you get this json in your ajax success:

```
const json = '[ {
    "company_name": "xyz Ltd",
    "company_email": "123@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "company_name": "wer Jit",
    "company_email": "2222@gmail.com"
  }]
';

const obj = JSON.parse(json); 
// you don't need this line, if you have set ajax datatype:'json'
```

you can get results for a single data set:

```
console.log(obj[0].company_name);
// this is how to get the first company name of the data set
// expected output: "xyz Ltd"
```

or you can loop through the whole data set

```
obj.forEach(element => $("#result").append(element.company_name + '<br>'));
```

see a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gxe9parb/)

conclusion: your ajax function could look just simply like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>email/get_company",
      data: {
        vals: vals
      },
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(data) {     
        obj.forEach(data => $("#result").append(data.company_name + '<br>'));    
      }
})
```